Im getting an error when i try to run this image recognizing code using pytorch
I am getting an error when running this code
import torch
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import os
import json

# Specify the path to the locally downloaded ResNet50 weights file
weights_path = '/Users/rishiamin/Downloads/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'  # Update with the actual path

# Load the pre-trained ResNet model
model = models.resnet50()
model.eval()

# Load the weights from the local file
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_path))

# Define the transformation for the input image
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Load labels for ImageNet classes from a local file
labels_path = '/Users/rishiamin/Desktop/imagenet-simple-labels.json'
with open(labels_path, 'r') as f:
    classes = json.load(f)

# Function to predict image
def predict_image_url(image_url):
    try:
        # Load image from URL with SSL certificate verification enabled
        response = requests.get(image_url, verify=True)
        response.raise_for_status()
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

        # Preprocess the image
        img = preprocess(img)
        img = img.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

        # Make predictions
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(img)

        # Get the predicted class
        _, predicted_idx = torch.max(output, 1)
        predicted_label = classes[predicted_idx.item()]

        print(f"Predicted Label: {predicted_label}")

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error loading image from URL: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

# Example usage
#Switch between http and https if link doesn't work
image_url = 'http://cdn.britannica.com/18/137318-050-29F7072E/rooster-Rhode-Island-Red-roosters-chicken-domestication.jpg'
predict_image_url(image_url)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rishiamin/PycharmProjects/Image Recognition/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_path))
  File "/Users/rishiamin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1040, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/Users/rishiamin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1258, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'.

I was expecting to get a one word answer from the image net simple labels as to what is in the picture i provided.

I'm guessing that the weights file was produced with an incompatible version of pickle.
